# Why is docker build taking so long to run?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running docker build and it's taking an awfully long time to run. Infact, it doesn't complete and I have to CTRL + C to quit.

Last night things were working fine. When I returned to the computer and tried to rebuild it started acting strange.

Here's my command:

```
docker build -t mywebsite/backend .
```

When I ran it I noticed this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 213.8 MB
Step 1 : FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

I have no idea why the file size was 213.8. The only directory that is large is `node_modules` and that contains `.dockerignore` so it shouldn't be touching that directory.

After that ran I had an error, so I fixed it and reran:

```
docker build -t mywebsite/backend .
```

This time it just hung. And continues to do so.

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Set env. variables
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# Application
ENV APP_PORT 3000

# Amazon
ENV AMAZON_BUCKET mybucket
ENV AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY_ID mykey
ENV AMAZON_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY mytoken

# Set working directory
WORKDIR ~/vms

# Install NodeJS
RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y curl;
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

# Install node dependencies
ADD package.json package.json
RUN npm install --production

# Copy files to the container
ADD src src

EXPOSE 3000

# Start application
RUN npm start
```

The directory I am in when I run the command is the one that contains the Dockerfile:

```
- backend
  - node_modules
  - src
    - config
    - routes
    - views
    index.js
  Dockerfile
  package.json
```

I'm running docker on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: when you do `docker build` are you in a directory with only the needed files for the docker build? I usually do `mkdir myproject ; cd myproject ; emacs Dockerfile`

Comment: May I ask why you use `ubuntu:14.04` instead of working with the [official node repository](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)? This way you woudn't have to install node each time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I have no idea why the file size was 213.8. The only directory that is large is node_modules and that contains .dockerignore so it shouldn't be touching that directory.

That's not how `.dockerignore` works. The `.dockerignore` file should be in the same directory as your `Dockerfile` and lists patterns to ignore. Create a file in `backend` called `.dockerignore` which simply contains the line `node_modules`.

See here for more information: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file

Answer (score -7):

What @sulogonamission says is perfect.

1. Create a file with the name `.dockerignore` in the directory where the Dockerfile exists
2. Add the following text to the file `/node_modules` (or the exact path of node_modules directory)
3. Save the file and run docker build again.

Comment: If what the other answer said is perfect, then why add another answer saying the same thing two years later?